# iOS 9 Auto rotation call ViewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios9

When i'm rotate device first time it call ViewDiDLoad method again. And it duplicate all observer methods. This strange issue appears only on iOS9.

Comment: And what is the question exactly?

Comment: Why it calls twice? and how i can fix this

Comment: Please update your question to be more clear.

Comment: maybe same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354825/ios8-rotation-issue-with-uitabbarcontroller-and-uinavigation-controller

Comment: @МатвейКозин , did you get the answer ?